# Проверка пароля в форме

Tags: python, django

помогите пожалуйста исправить ошибку

я проверяю в forms.py пароль пользователя

```
from django import forms
from userprofile.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm

class ChangePasswordForm(forms.Form):
    password_old = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    def clean_password_old(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        password_old = cleaned_data.get("password_old") 
        if not User.check_password(password_old):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords is not correct")
        else:
            return cleaned_data

    def clean(self):    
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        password1 = cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = cleaned_data.get("password2")

        if password1 != password2:      
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords must be same")
        else:                           
            return cleaned_data
```

но после отправки формы получаю на экран следующее сообщение об ошибке:

```
TypeError at /userprofile/password_page/
check_password() missing 1 required positional argument: 'raw_password'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/userprofile/password_page/
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
check_password() missing 1 required positional argument: 'raw_password'
```

то есть проблема в проверке пароля (password_old) перед операцией замены(с операцией замены проблем нет, она в представлении)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь сделать check_password у класса, в то врмя как нужно делать у его экземпляра. То есть у конкретного юзера.

Вам нужно делать смену пароля в представлении, где вы можете получить request с текущим юзером

Comment: Либо передавать request.user в конструктор формы, чтобы использовать его в стандартной валидации

Comment: вот как раз и не понятно как передать из request.user из представления в форму(

а проверка пароля у меня давно уже реализована. не в этом проблема

Comment: views.py

    form = ChangePasswordForm(request.POST or None, request=request)

forms.py:

    class ChangePasswordForm(forms.Form):
        def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            self.request = request
            super(ChangePasswordForm, self).__init__(request, *args, **kwargs)

и у вас в любом месте в self.request.user всегда свеженький пользователь

Comment: что-то не получается. django говорит, что все именованные аргументы в kwargs находятся. __init__() got multiple values for argument 'request'.
вот я нашёл похожую ситуацию http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941812/django-error-got-multiple-values-for-keyword-argument#1941812 ,но всё равно не получается объект request.user получить и вызывать request.user.check_password(old)

Comment: извиняюсь за мозгоклюйство с моей стороны. всё получилось. спасибо большое